# Why Activities are not getting garbage collected?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my app I am switching between activities using intents. The flags I set are :

Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

I am calling finish() after starting the activities, however as I type 'dumpsys' command in the terminal it shows multiple activites after I switch between activities a few times.

Why is the previous activites that I launched not getting garbage collected?[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgdxT.png)

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download MAT
2. Execute `SELECT * FROM instanceof android.app.Activity`
3. Check external links that prevent your activities from being garbage collected

Comment: Where am I supposed to type the Query? In OQL?